# Is “Did you it?” a valid question?

Tags: questions

My English teacher always asks “Did you it?” when she wants to know whether some student has done an exercise.

I think her question sounds horrible, and I believe it is wrong. In my opinion, she should say “Did you do it?” instead.

I would like to know whether “Did you it?” is in fact wrong.

Comment: "Did you it" makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Tell her "syntax error, does not compute". Without a wild card character (`!` or `*` or `?`) to take the place of _action_, _complete_, _do_, _execute_, _follow_ or _understand_, it definitely makes no sense... ;-P

Comment: "Did you it" is grammatically correct and even means what your teacher intends it to mean. It is, however, not what a native speaker of English would say. So it is neither right nor wrong, you could say.

Comment: She is not a native speaker and makes a lot of grammatical errors when she speaks. However, in this case I wanted to be sure that it is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to judge but unless you missed class the day your teacher explained why he/she would use such a fractured version of a question, I think it would be doing students a disservice to think that question is acceptable among average english-speaking people.

Comment: @MετάEd I would argue that questions using simple inversion without a *do*-auxiliary are no longer grammatical in Contemporary Standard English.  Not even the *Silmarillion* uses it.  Nor the *Lays of Beleriand*.

Comment: She could ask "You did it?" instead.

Comment: @MετάEd: under what possible set of rules could "Did you it" be construed as grammatical? (Where's the rest of the verb?) And what on earth is it supposed to *mean*?

Comment: @Martha: It looks to me to be exactly the same structure as [Saw you that, sir?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22saw+you+that+sir%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which might be a bit archaic, but is hardly *ungrammatical* as such. It's just a construction we don't normally use these days.

Comment: Is your teacher an AmE native speaker? I think it's possible that if you slur together "Did you do it?" fast enough you can come out with something like "Did-juh-ooh-it?" Which can morph pretty easily to become "Did-jew-it?"  Which sounds very similar to "Did you it".

Comment: ...okay, maybe it's a *lot* archaic. But it was good enough for Shakespeare in The Merry Wives of Windsor - [Mrs. Page: "Heard you that?"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=K_EjAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=%22page+heard+you+that%22&source=bl&ots=c-SlgxNjEA&sig=j5L-5ION14F9XAgNSJz-RUAwLvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bjGYUNXJB-O20QWG_4GwAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22page%20heard%20you%20that%22&f=false)

Comment: There's an 1825 Gaelic dictionary that uses "_Did you it?_" in Google Books: A Gaelic Dictionary in Two Parts. Page 1015 books.google.com/books?id=r4Bk4KKEjvMC Robert Archibald Armstrong - 1825 -...Why did you it ? c'arson a ... And there are plenty of early 19th-century books that have "_Have you it?_", but the Ngram is down to almost zero by 1960. It's perfectly grammatical but archaic English. Ben Jonson used it in 1816: "
Where is the warrant—0fi'icer, have you it? Brai. No, sir, your worship's man, master Formal,

Comment: That's as good as WS's using it in 1616, so anyone who says it's wrong is quite mistaken. FumbleFingers has it right: "might be a bit archaic, but is hardly ungrammatical as such. It's just a construction we don't normally use these days." No stiff-necked beast he.

Comment: All grammar aside, be diplomatic in the way you approach your teacher about the results posted here on ESE (if you approach your teacher at all). Being "right" in this case may not mean you will be happy with the consequences.

Comment: Do, or not do...there is no it -- Yoda

Comment: @JeffSahol: True disciple of Yoda you are not. **It** says only that there is no *"**try**"*, only *"**do**"*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A [yes–no question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion#In_questions) that begins “Did you. . . ?” is invariably, or mandatorily, a *do*-auxiliary inversion.  It cannot stand alone as an actual non-auxiliary.  You have no verb afterwards, because *to it* is not English.  You cannot say any of these:

- Spoke you it?
- Called you her?
- Ran you the race?
- Think you so?
- Called you?
- Gave you it?
- Proposed him to her?
- Have you it?
- Did you it?

in Contemporary English.  That is super-archaic.  It might not even be understood.

It is very hard, but not impossible, to make sentences with only pronouns but no verbs come off as grammatical.  Here is one such example:

> “What about the Smiths?  I gave her a letter.”
>
> “And I, him.”

But just having a lone, inverted *do*-auxiliary without a verb for it to help out on is not going to work.

Comment: Does it actually make any difference whether there's an [indirect] object/pronoun after a question framed as *verb + [pro]noun?*. Unless I'm missing a trick here, we always use [do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) today, so you have to say *"Did you vote?"* rather than *"Voted you?"*

Comment: "Have you a candle?" is legit, no?

Comment: @Charles: That's pretty "marginal" in contemporary English. We'd nearly all say either *"Do you have a candle?"*, or *"Have you got a candle?"*.

Comment: ...but actually, I don't have any real problem with [Have you time to {do something}](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have+you+time+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which still seems to be "current", if a little stilted.

Comment: "Have you a good reason for not doing your homework?" would probably be preferred by some - perhaps most - people over "Have you got a good reason for not doing your homework?" There is little logic behind what is and what is not allowed, and why usage has changed over the years. "A good time was had by all" is a very rare allowed passive usage of _have_ (in this sense): "A problem is being had, Houston", or even "A whale of a time was had by us all" are ungrammatical.

Comment: @Charles Just about to ask the same question. Not with candles, though :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Have you a light?" has plenty of internet hits with the expected meaning: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22have+you+a+light%3F%22

Comment: @Charles I would interpret "Have you a candle?" as a second-language-English speaker offering a candle to me...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The most natural version of that question is, “Do you have a good reason for not doing your homework?” Any version of it beginning with “Have you a good. . . .” sounds several centuries out of date.

Comment: @Charles: We're exploring the margins of "acceptability" here. I think Edwin has come up with some excellent examples of where many of us draw the line. But in the end, we're all going to be idiosyncratic in what we do and don't accept as "normal speech patterns" here.

Comment: @tchrist: Have you any sound justification for that position? I think not, sirrah! (Ooops - might have blown my cover with that second sentence! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Did you really that?

Comment: It were a joke. But I still think Edwin has you on the ropes regarding your excessively dogmatic "grammatical" position here (I have no idea what linguists mean by "grammatically valid" these days! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers As was my response; must I smiley everything of humorous content? I was merely repeating the OP’s question, you see. The point remains that while something like “Think you so?” is formal perhaps even to the point of being archaic, that something like “Did you it?” is at best obsolete, for if ever it was understandable, that day is long past. It cannot coëxist with our modern *do*-auxiliary yes–no question syntax, against which it gardenpaths to nonsense.  The OP is 110% right on this.

Comment: I doubt anyone here is seriously going to defend OP's teacher as a competent speaker (or, by implication, as a competent *teacher* - twat that she is). But there are certainly contexts where you can get away with a *verb - [pro]noun* question format without sounding too medieval. Given the popularity of that form in Hollywood sci-fi/fantasy, it'll probably end up becoming fashionable again soon!

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Baa bah black sheep, have you any wool?* Plus various from JRRT, Gene Wolfe, George Martin: “Have you *athelas?”* “Or have you no wits left?” “Have you a guess?”  // “Have you need of money?” “Had they reason to hate me?” “Have you faith in the coming of the New Sun?” “Have you a knife?” // “Have you no honor?” her aunt said sharply. “Have you no smile for me?” Has he a good heart, a gentle hand? “Have you proof of that?” “Lord Captain, have you no greeting for a brother long away?” “The big crow can peck the little crows, [...] but has he belly enough to fight 
a man?”

Comment: I can't tell if the teacher is competent or not – there's not enough information given. When I first saw this question, though, I found myself wondering: is her verbiage _intentionally_ archaic, designed to make the students wonder, "Is that even a valid question?" If that's the case, just look over the discussion that's been generated – mission accomplished. Perhaps the teacher is a dolt – too many of them are – but she could just as well be a brilliant teacher who would smile at the passionate discussion that's been sparked. Agree ye?

Comment: @J.R., I don't think it was intentional or that she's a dolt. The OP said in a comment on the question "She is not a native speaker and makes a lot of grammatical errors when she speaks."